# CONCAT with Comma

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to concatenate two fields in Oracle SQL Developer.

I managed to concatenate them, but I need to separate them with a comma.

I tried to do so using this code, but it didn't work.

Can anyone please advise how I should change the code? It worked without the ', ' in the middle of the query, but didn't give a comma.

```
CONCAT(shipto_addr1, ', ', shipto_city)
```

Comment: Oracle's CONCAT() takes only 2 parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `||` operator instead of `CONCAT()`:

```
(shipto_addr1 || ', ' || shipto_city)
```

The `concat()` function in Oracle only accepts two arguments, alas.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt response. When I ran that, I got this error: ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments
00909. 00000 -  "invalid number of arguments"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 42

Comment: Do you know why that may be? This is the full code: select HOMOGENIZED_COMPANY, contract_no, CONCAT(shipto_addr1 || ', ' || shipto_city), RESTATED_DISTRIBUTOR, software_vendor, CONCAT(RESTATED_DISTRIBUTOR, software_vendor), sum(new_annual) ACV  from pp_finance_bank
where contract_no in ('Z0101-S-00003687')
group by HOMOGENIZED_COMPANY, contract_no, CONCAT(shipto_addr1 || ', ' || shipto_city), RESTATED_DISTRIBUTOR,software_vendor,CONCAT(RESTATED_DISTRIBUTOR, software_vendor) 
;

Comment: @Mr2017 You need `shipto_addr1 || ', ' || shipto_city` instead of `CONCAT(shipto_addr1 || ', ' || shipto_city)`

Comment: Would you be able to incorporate what you mean in the actual query, please?

Comment: Actually, sorry @Mithrandir - and thank you! Your amendment worked! Thanks again!

Comment: Is there a way to create a column where you join the two fields, using the mehthod that you used above, but only take ONE field, if both fields are the same? So if bith fields have the word 'London' in them, then the concatenated column would just show London. But if one filed had 'London' and the other field had 'England' then it would show 'London; England'?

Comment: @Mr2017 . . . Yes, but that is not the question you asked here.  A new question should be asked as a *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to nest the `concat` to process more than two paramaters

```
select 
   CONCAT(CONCAT('shipto_addr1',', '), 'shipto_city') txt
from dual;   

TXT                      
-------------------------
shipto_addr1, shipto_city
```

But as stated elsewhere using the `||` operator is probably more user friendly